# trying to calc average with $avg and got: arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, aggregation

got this error: arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators
this is the course 'Schema" that got bootcamp as objectId.

```
   const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   bootcamp: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Bootcamp',
        required: true
    }
  });
```

the aggregation :

```
 //static method to get avg of course tuitions
    CourseSchema.statics.getAverageCost = async function (bootcampId) {
    console.log('calculating avg cost... with bootcampId:' + bootcampId);
    const obj = await this.aggragate([{
        $match: { bootcamp: bootcampId },
        $group: {
            _id: '$bootcamp',
            averageCost: { $avg: '$tuition' }
        }
    }]);
    console.log(obj);
    }
```

calling for the aggregation before saving or removing:

...

```
// Call getAvarageCost after save
CourseSchema.post('save', function () {
    this.constructor.getAverageCost(this.bootcamp);
})

// Call getAvarageCost before remove
CourseSchema.post('remove', function () {
    this.constructor.getAverageCost(this.bootcamp);
})
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$match and $group must be in different pipeline operations

```
const cursor = this.aggregate([
  { $match: { bootcamp: bootcampId } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$bootcamp',
      averageCost: { $avg: '$tuition' },
    },
  },
])
console.log(await cursor.toArray())
```

Comment: hey, thanks but now I got another problem with
Error: this.aggragate is not a function 
const obj = await this.aggragate

Comment: never mind .. this.aggregate .... nottttt this.AGRRAGATE.. 2 days .. 2 loving days

Comment: btw you dont need "toArray" at the end

Comment: oops typos must be `aggregate`

Comment: toArray - give you array

aggregate give you Aggregation cursor, async iterable..